# Setting a property within a class that has an internal setter for use in testing (C#)

Tags: c#, njsonschema

I'm using NJsonSchema to validate JSON input.

I have a small class that takes a collection of `ValidationError` objects and creates more user friendly error messages using the contents of each validation error.

I want to be able to write unit tests for this class, however I have came across a problem. One of the message handlers within my class has the responsibility of handling `NotInEnumeration` errors, and for this it uses the `Enumeration` property within the `JsonSchema4` object held within the ValidationError and creates a nicely formatted error message.

When writing a test for this particular handler I discovered that the following is illegal:

```
JsonSchema4 enumSchema = new JsonSchema4();
enumSchema.Enumeration = new List<object>{ "A", "B", "C" };
```

This is because the Enumeration property has an internal setter.

I need to be able to set the enumeration of a validation error as the object needs to be passed through to the ValidationError's constructor, which is then read later on by my handler, as below.

```
private string NotInEnumerationHandler(ValidationError error)
        {
            var userFriendlyErrorString = "Answer must be within range: ";
            var enumString = "[" + string.Join<object>(", ", error.Schema.Enumeration) + "]";
            userFriendlyErrorString += enumString;
            return userFriendlyErrorString;
        }
```

I cannot mock the JsonSchema4 object using moq as moq doesn't allow mocking of non-virtual methods.

Essentially the details aren't really important, but I'd like to know if there's any way of setting an internal setter so that I can test this particular method within my class.

Comment: You can make your test-assembly a friend-project of your system under test using the `InternalsVisibleTo`-attribute in your `AssemblyInfo.cs`. This way you should be able to access the internal setter also.

Comment: Enumeration is an ICollection. Why not simply Add() the items you need?

Comment: @IvayloStoev You know when you just can't see the wood for trees?

Comment: happens to me all the time :-)

Answer (score 1):

`JsonSchema4.Enumeration` is an `ICollection<Object>` .

Therefore I don't need to set the value of `Enumeration` to a new colletion, I can just add the items I want into the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to set, first you need to get the property info of the property and then set the value to the instance you created.

```
var enumSchema = new JsonSchema4();
var propertyInfo = typeof(JsonSchema4).GetProperty("Enumeration", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
propertyInfo.SetValue(enumSchema, new List<object> { "A", "B", "C" });
```

And this is how you can verify it worked

```
Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.GetValue(enumSchema, null));
```

You could make some extension method to provide you the "Enumeration" property in your test assembly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, I just had too much to put in a comment and also it doesn't format correctly.
Here's a sample of what your AssemblyInfo.cs should look like:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Assembly.Fully.Qualified.Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]

#if DEBUG
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Assembly.Fully.Qualified.Name")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
#endif
```

You need the bottom of the two Attributes `DynamicProxyGenAssembly2` in order for Moq to be able to see the internals. You might not need a Debug and Release switch in which case don't bother with the `#if DEBUG` section.